# When to set session to false when using passport js res.redirection is not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, passport.js, backend

I have complete authanticaton like this with middle ware useing passport authantication

```
function (req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('magic-link-signin', function (err, user, info) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }
          if (!user) { return res.redirect(`${CLIENT_ORIGIN_SIGNUP}&rc=true`); }
      
          req.logIn(user, { session: false }, function (err) {
      
            // Should not cause any errors      
            if (err) { return next(err); }
               //when user or candidate status pending then magic link email link redirect to the wp site and with access token and user id

             const { _id, status }: any = user;
             const { token } = req.query;
             const id = _id.split(':');
            
             if(status === pendingStatus){
               //set in production .gritserach.com domain
               res.cookie('at',token, { maxAge: Number(COOKIE_REFER_MAXAGE), httpOnly: false, domain: COOKIE_REFER_DOMAIN, path: '/', secure: true });
               res.cookie('userId',id[1], { maxAge: Number(COOKIE_REFER_MAXAGE), httpOnly: false, domain: COOKIE_REFER_DOMAIN, path: '/', secure: true });                  
               return res.redirect(CLIENT_ORIGIN_SIGNUP);
             }
             new AuthController().login(req, res, next);
          });
        })(req, res, next);
      }
```

magic-link-singin function is

```
this.passport.use('magic-link-signin', new MagicLinkStrategy(
            this.jwtOptions,
            async (user, done) => {
                const userFound = await UserService.getUserByEmail(user.email, true);
                
                if (!userFound) {
                    return done(null, false);
                }

                // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
                const { password: userPassword, ...userWithoutPass } = userFound
                return done(null, userWithoutPass);
            }
        ));
```

there is getting in console log cors origin issue. like this
[image]

res.redirect(CLIENT_ORIGIN_SIGNUP); not work...
any one can help me. :(

Comment: do you get any errors? It would be nice to see the code for this passport auth method `magic-link-signin`

Comment: sure.. I have added magic-link-signin function

Comment: Don't say it doesn't work. Rather explain 1. What you do. 2. What happens. 3. What you expect to happen instead. In "What happens" also include any logs / error logs

Comment: if you console.log(user, err) just before  if (err) { return next(err); }

Comment: what do you get?